# is posible Remote development on SharePoint 2013 with no Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-server, apps-development, visual-studio-2013

I have:

- VM with SharePoint 2013 installation, I'm not using Active Directory.
- Laptop with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 and Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013

Is there a way to remote development using this configuration?

I've read some documentation and it says that is possible if you add a specific user to Administrators group on SharePoint 2013 and then log in to your development laptop with the same user. My problem is that I'm not using Active Directory, I'm using just local users.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an user to your local users and groups in the machine and those users can be used in your sharepoint application